# Securing react router 4 routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Started a new project using the latest version of React Router.

I have routes that are wrapped with an `Auth` component.

```
    <Route exact path="/" render={ (props) => (
      <Auth loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn}>
        <Dashboard {...props} deletePage={this.deletePage} pages={this.state.pages} />
      </Auth>
    )} />
```

The App container then sends the state of loggedIn to the Auth component:

```
class Auth extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log(this.props.loggedIn)
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    return !this.props.loggedIn ? window.location.replace('/admin/login') : null
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       {this.props.loggedIn ? this.props.children : null}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But in React Dev tools I can easily just change the state to true and have full access to the site. What's the best way in dealing with this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, 
security isn't a client concern, this is what the data layer is supposed to do.

Even if somebody opening the console sets `isLoggedIn = true` then the server shouldn't allow him to do anything.

By the way, 
the good way (in my opinion) is to provide async server side resource authorisations: **ask the server** what the current user is able to do...

React router has middlewares, so, this is really easy to implement.

Comment: Ahh makes sense of course. Do you have any examples?

Comment: What middlewares are you referring to? Can you please elaborate?